# How to flatten XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml

Is there a library or mechanism I can use to flatten the XML file?

Existing:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <ConnectionType>a</ConnectionType>
        <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
        <EndTime>00:00:00</EndTime>
        <UseDataDictionary>N</UseDataDictionary>
```

Desired:

```
A.B.ConnectionType = a
A.B.StartTime = 00:00:00
A.B.EndTime = 00:00:00
A.B.UseDataDictionary = N
```

Comment: I'd have a look at the [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) library in combination with [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/21035) answer to flatten a `dict`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) to transform your XML file to a dictionary, in combination with [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/21035) to flatten a `dict`, this should be possible.

Example:

```
# Original code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/21035
from collections import OrderedDict

def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
            else:
                yield key, value

    return OrderedDict(items())

import xmltodict

# Convert to dict
with open('test.xml', 'rb') as f:
    xml_content = xmltodict.parse(f)

# Flatten dict
flattened_xml = flatten_dict(xml_content)

# Print in desired format
for k,v in flattened_xml.items():
    print('{} = {}'.format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
A.B.ConnectionType = a
A.B.StartTime = 00:00:00
A.B.EndTime = 00:00:00
A.B.UseDataDictionary = N
```

Comment: for anyone like myself, that doesnt do much python, you can install the modules required to use this script by running `pip install xmltodict` and `pip install OrderedDict`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a  complete implementation but you could take advantage of [lxmls's getpath](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath):

```
xml = """<A>
            <B>
               <ConnectionType>a</ConnectionType>
               <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
               <EndTime>00:00:00</EndTime>
               <UseDataDictionary>N
               <UseDataDictionary2>G</UseDataDictionary2>
               </UseDataDictionary>
            </B>
       </A>"""


from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))

root = tree.getroot().tag
for node in tree.iter():
    for child in node.getchildren():
         if child and child.text.strip():
            print("{}.{} = {}".format(root, ".".join(tree.getelementpath(child).split("/")), child.text.strip()))
```

Which gives you:

```
A.B.ConnectionType = a
A.B.StartTime = 00:00:00
A.B.EndTime = 00:00:00
A.B.UseDataDictionary = N
A.B.UseDataDictionary.UseDataDictionary2 = G
```

Comment: well this is a very nice solution but it's not working with the below XML string 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>18</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improved version from [ƘɌỈsƬƠƑ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3165737/%C6%98%C9%8C%E1%BB%88s%C6%AC%C6%A0%C6%91) that also handles nested lists:

```py
def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            # nested subtree
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield '{}.{}'.format(key, subkey), subvalue
            # nested list
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for num, elem in enumerate(value):
                    for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(elem).items():
                        yield '{}.[{}].{}'.format(key, num, subkey), subvalue
            # everything else (only leafs should remain)
            else:
                yield key, value
```

Comment: I am new to python so can you add the working example. @alexeykorobov